# Get a UILabel from Storyboard programmatically without viewWithTag or IBOutlet

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uilabel

I got an UILabel from my Storyboard using the "viewWithTag" programmatically, but I want to know if is it possible to get this UILabel using a string from "restorationIdentifier" or "accessibilityIdenfier" properties.

```
var myLabel:UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    myLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel
    myLabel.text = "Text changed programatically"
    
}
```

Is there another way to do that using a String instead of a Int using "viewWithTag" ?

ps: I want to avoid the use of IBOutlets in Storyboard